# Name of a difference of continuants

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, continued-fractions, terminology

I am getting ready to publish the manuscript

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4631v2.pdf

and I am trying to do due diligence on a quantity I study before it gets published.  (This is cross-posted from [Name/properties of a difference of continuants](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/938147).)

Suppose that $q_1$, $\ldots$, $q_s$ is a sequence of positive integers.  Denote by $[q_1, \ldots, q_s]$ the numerator (in lowest terms) of the rational number represented by the continued fraction

$$
q_1 + \cfrac{1}{q_2 + \cfrac{1}{q_3 + \cfrac{1}{\ddots \, + \cfrac{1}{q_s}}}}
$$
The expression $[q_1, \ldots, q_s]$ is a polynomial in $q_1$, $\ldots$, $q_s$, called the *continuant* of $q_1$, $\ldots$, $q_s$.

It is not hard to show using standard properties of continuants that for a given positive integer $n$, there are only finitely many sequences of positive integers $q_1$, $\ldots$, $q_s$ with
$$
[q_1, \ldots, q_s] - [q_2, \ldots, q_{s-1}] = n
$$
(Let's make the conventions that the left side is just $q_1$ and $q_1 q_2$ in the cases $s=1$ and $s=2$ respectively).  The proof I give in the paper instead puts them in one-to-one correspondence with a finite collection of binary quadratic forms.

Because the above fact is not hard to prove, I would surmise it has appeared before.  My questions:

1) Does the expression $[q_1, \ldots, q_s] - [q_2, \ldots, q_{s-1}]$ have a standard name?

2) What use has been made of it?

Comment: 1) Probably, no. But you gave them a good name. 2) Do they have geometrical interpretation?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know.

Comment: One place you might want to look is [**History of Continued Fractions and Padé Approximants**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/3540152865) by Claude Brezinski.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked that book out, and didn't find anything.  Interestingly, Brezinski says "many results which were obtained during the nineteenth century are now completely forgotten and have to be rediscovered".  Regardless, I'll go ahead and stick with the name "alternant".